# How hard would it be to manipulate a 3d model in flash with the mouse?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, papervision3d, away3d

Using a common flash 3d library such as Papervision3d or away3d & as3dmod or better create a Flash 3d object manipulator that:

- Loads a complex 3d object (for example a pottery item)
- Allows a user to rotate the object
- Allows a user to grab vertices with the mouse and stretch them like so:

  - Drag on x-axis(symmetrical - changes
    affect a given points area across
    that points entire section - i.e. to
    widen a pot)
  - Drag on x-axis(non-symmetrical - changes affect a given points area, but local to that area only - i.e. when rotating you can see a bulge or a indent)
  - Drag on y-axis(symmetrical - changes affect a given points area across that points entire section - i.e. to make a pot taller from the given point)
  - Drag on y-axis(non-symmetrical - changes affect a given points area, but local to that area only - i.e. to make a pot taller but in a skewed way...like the leaning tower of piza or something)
  - Drag on x & y axis (symmetrical - to
    resize basically)
  - Drag on x & y axis (non-symmetrical - 
    this would be the pliable version of the transform, where whatever the
    user does affects the local area in
    a set way - i.e. to really mangle a
    pot, or if your skilled make it real
    nice)
- Finally Allows a user to capture & download a picture of said object after manipulation

Comment: How hard compared to what? Not hard compared to the moon landings, hard compared to making a cup of tea. Compared to the average Flash site? Pretty hard.

Comment: :) like if your average PV3D action is a chewy cookie...what is bullet point 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bullet points 1 and 2 are easy (or at least, very possible with little effort.)  For 1, just make sure you are using a file type for which the 3d engine has a corresponding file parser.  For example, both PV3D and away3d support 3ds files.

Bullet point 4 is easy as well.  You can use adobe's [as3corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) image classes to generate a JPG or PNG in flash and do with it what you want from there.

Bullet point 3 is, as @alecmce said, pretty hard.  I have used both PV3D and away3d quite a bit but I have never had the need to attempt what you are talking about here.  For that I am thankful because I have a hard time following some of the math used in 3d rendering engine, let alone a 3d polygon manipulation tool.  Eeek.

Comment: yeah 1 & 2 are done, 3 seems to be well beyond the norm & 4 seems simple enough...I wonder if anyone has a conceptual method to pull this off...i.e using mouseover&down/up change a models vertices coordinates on the fly and apply transformation math to surrounding vertices